# Huge number of wait_to_close sessions

Tags: java, html, lightstreamer

I'm connecting to the light streamer server from an HTML5 client, the client uses a javascript code in order to connect to the light streamer, I have another java client which connects to the light streamer server, both clients uses the same data adapter on the light streamer server.

HTML5 has it's own light streamer server, and the java client has it's own light streamer server.

However, when the number of customers increases, the behaviour is totally different between the java and the HTML5, We found a huge number of WAIT TO CLOSE sessions on the HTML5 LS server, but nothing happened on the java side.

I have read the log and I have found the following line repeated too many times:

**31-Aug-20 14:10:37,592|INFO |LightstreamerLogger.requests     |FOR PUMPS PARKING DESTROYER|Closed session S97cc068f69302361T1037592 with internal cause code: 38 (Interrupted).
(99% of the total repetitions)**

**31-Aug-20 10:59:55,136|INFO |LightstreamerLogger.requests     |FOR PUMPS PARKING DESTROYER|Closed session Sd801e961cc64051cT5925121 with internal cause code: 39 (Timeout).
(1% of the total repetitions)**

*These two records repeated 117058 for 2000 users starting from 9:30 up to 14:15*

Would you please help me with this serious issue?

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, do you mean that you see many TCP sockets in CLOSE_WAIT state in the machine running the instance of LS Server that serves the HTML5 clients?

Comment: exactly @AlessandroAlinone

Comment: Ok, only the logs can help understand it better. You can post them to forums.lightstreamer.com.

Comment: @AlessandroAlinone, I have modified my question, further, I have posted my question with the same title on the Lightstreamer forums.

unfortunately, I couldn't upload the logs there for some reason and because of this I have mentioned the most repeated lines which is related to this issue (based on my analysis).